# How to read extra info from MINEW Eddystone BLE beacon by Python on RaspberyPi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone, gatttool

according to the documentation,
MINEW Eddystone beacon responds in the following format:

```
{"timestamp": "2018-01-22T11:10:28Z", "type": "Unknown", "mac": "AC233F23FFCE", "bleName": "", "rssi": -59, "rawData": "0201060303E1FF1016E1FFA10864CEFF233F23AC504C5553" }
```

The *rawData* contains Battery Charge Level.
I've tried libraries ***beaconntools***, ***bleak***, ***iBeacon-Scanner***, tool ***gatttool*** and some others, they all can connect to a beacon and read MAC and some other scrambled information,
but I've never managed to get response in the given JSON format or get something like the *rawData* in order to extract Battery Charge Level.

Which library can do that in Python on Raspberry Pi?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @ukBaz , you are great! How would I enforce **bluetoothctl** to show *ServiceData*?

Comment: I have run *scan on* in **bluetoothctl** output is:                    ' [CHG] Device AC:23:3F:58:44:A1 RSSI: -34
[CHG] Device AC:23:3F:58:44:A1 ServiceData Key: 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:23:3F:58:44:A1 ServiceData Value:
  10 e8 01 6d 69 6e 65 77 00                       ...minew.'                                                           **ServiceData** does not look like **rawData**

Comment: [aioblescan](https://github.com/frawau/aioblescan). isn't working. *python3 -m aioblescan* command brings no response

Comment: I am also trying to parse this rawdata to extract the battery level from minew beacon. Can you please share how did you resolve it?